# Hash of hashes from arrays in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I am using two arrays (one that holds keys and one that holds values) to build a hash in Perl.  I need to count and delete the repeated key/value pairs so that I have a unique hash.  Then I have to build a hash of hashes of the form: ((key,value), count).

I am using this line to build the hash from the arrays.

```
@hash{@keys} = @values;
```

This will keep repeated key/value pairs in the hash which I do not want.  Any help in creating the hash of hashes is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Hash slicing (the thing you're doing) is a great way to zip two ordered arrays together, but I don't think it's a good fit for the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen Any suggestions for a better approach?

Comment: Not 100% sure about your intended hash of hash structure (`((key,value), count)`). A Key/Value pair can't be a hash key, has to be a string

Comment: I just need some way to count the number of occurrences for a key/value pair @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Can you give some example data and a desired result? Key collision mean you can't slice them together, because that will overwrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you arrays look like this:

```
my @keys   = qw/a b c a a/;
my @values = qw/1 2 3 4 1/;
```

It's as easy as a simple for loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < scalar @keys; $i++) {
    $hash{$keys[$i]}{$values[$i]} += 1;
}
```

You can then iterate over the inner values (the count) with a nested loop:

```
foreach my $key (keys %hash) {
    while (my ($value, $count) = each %{ $hash{$key} } ) {
        print "$key : $value = $count\n";
    }
}
```

Which would produce:

```
c : 3 = 1
a : 4 = 1
a : 1 = 2
b : 2 = 1
```

You can sort the keys if you want to:

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %hash) {
    # same as before 
}
```

To get

```
a : 4 = 1
a : 1 = 2
b : 2 = 1
c : 3 = 1
```

Comment: I tried printing values from this hash of hashes using
foreach $item (keys %hash){
  print "$item: ";
   foreach $iteminitem (keys %{$hash{$item}}){
         print "$iteminitem = $hash{$item}{$iteminitem} ";
   }
   print "\n";
}
in the form: key: value = count
but the output produces a: 1 = 1
when I want it to show a: 1 = 2 since there are two a keys with values of 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash of hashes, where each key hash a subhash of the form `value => count`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @keys   = qw( k1 k1 k1 k2 k2 k3 k4 k4 k5);
my @values = qw( v1 v2 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v6 v7 );

my %hash;
for my $idx (0 .. $#keys) {
    $hash{ $keys[$idx] }{ $values[$idx] }++;
}

print Dumper \%hash;
```

Comment: I tried printing values from this hash of hashes using
foreach $item (keys %hash){
  print "$item: ";
   foreach $iteminitem (keys %{$hash{$item}}){
         print "$iteminitem = $hash{$item}{$iteminitem} ";
   }
   print "\n";
}
in the form: key: value = count
and it showed k1: v2 = 1
when I want it to show k1: v2 = 2 since there are two k1 keys with values of v2

Comment: @CSstudent: Very strange. Shows `k1: v2 = 2 v1 = 1` for me (after adding `my` to loop variables).